# Blackberry OS version limit

Tags: blackberry, java-me, push-notification

Is there a OS version limit to accept blackberry push, or for JSON parsing.
for example, BB OS version 5.0 and above or 6.0 and above.

I have BB device 6.0 and my app works fine on it, can someone please tell me, if my application will work on OS 5.0 too?
My application also contains, push notification, http connection and json parsing.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIS Push will work the same way.  OS 6.0 added a JSON parser, so if your code depends on that, you will have to bring in a third-party JSON parser, and make use of it, in order to build against OS5.

Comment: Hey Michael, can u please temme bout third-party JSON parser? Like is there any standard one, or can you suggest me one..

Answer (score 1):

For 6.0 and above JSON API is added in SDK , but for lower versions check this [link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/JSON-library/td-p/573687) download the library from that link